# freebase year of death

Tags: freebase

freebase users!

i'm trying to get this results:

- list of all people who died in 2011
- list of all americans who died in 2011

i use python code with simple query:

```
import freebase
r = freebase.mqlreaditer({"/people/deceased_person/date_of_death":'2011', "name":None})
for i in r:
    print i
```

But output gives me like 20 names. Comparing results to this article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:2011_deaths) - 5,612 names, obvioulsy there's some error.

Any ideas how to get correct results?

Answer (score 1):

The query that you wrote:

```
{
  "name": null,
  "/people/deceased_person/date_of_death": "2011"
}​
```

This only finds people who's date of death is recorded in Freebase as "2011". What you intended to query was people who died on or after Jan. 1, 2011 but before Jan. 1, 2012. That query looks like this:

```
{
  "id": null,
  "name": null,
  "type": "/people/deceased_person",
  "date_of_death": null,
  "date_of_death>=": "2011",
  "date_of_death<": "2012"
}​
```

You can further refine that query to only search for Americans like this:

```
{
  "id": null,
  "name": null,
  "type": "/people/deceased_person",
  "date_of_death": null,
  "date_of_death>=": "2011",
  "date_of_death<": "2012",
  "/people/person/nationality": {
    "id": "/en/united_states"
  }
}​
```

Note that since nationality is part of /people/person and not /people/deceased_person (the declared type), I need to use the full property ID whereas date_of_death can use the shortened ID.